# Converting two double values to String and then making a string using the new strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am trying to convert two values to string and then make a new string containing the ones i made earlier so my service can accept them.

```
NSString *string1 = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationController.dblLatitude];
NSString *string2 = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationController.dblLongitude];



body = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoX#%@#geoY#%@", string1, string2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the code i am using atm. The problem is that both string1 and string2 appear to be ok but the string named body appears to not working.. :< Any help ?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output e.g. what values you have in string1, string2 and body?

Comment: I have coordinates that i get from an updatelocation method. e.g 37.785834. I get two of these that i want to join them in a string of this format geoX#string1#geoY#string2 so my rest service can accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is not an `NSString` instance here, but `NSData` (because you're using `dataUsingEncoding:".
If you want to see concatenation of stings in system log you should write something like that:

```
NSString* bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoX#%@#geoY#%@", string1, string2];
NSData* bodyData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and then you can `NSLog(@"Body: %@", bodyString);` to see it's contents and then use `bodyData` for making http request.

Comment: Really thanks all. Idd body was NSData and not NSString although i had it in front of my eyes i was really confused. This is working great now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`body` is not an `NSString`; it is an `NSData` because of your call to `dataUsingEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you are just logging the raw data. Try creating a string from the data and then logging it like this:

```
body = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoX#%@#geoY#%@", string1, string2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```